# Create a ray cluster in azure

Tags: python, azure, ray

I don't have a ray cluster so the following code sample from the docs I want to implement gives an error https://github.com/oap-project/raydp .how do I create a ray cluster in azure?

I have seen this  https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/ai-machine-learning-blog/library-to-turn-azure-ml-compute-into-ray-and-dask-cluster/ba-p/3048784  but cant use a virtual network so does not work any alternative ways?

```
import ray
import raydp

# connect to ray cluster
ray.init(address='auto')

# create a Spark cluster with specified resource requirements
spark = raydp.init_spark(app_name='RayDP Example',
                         num_executors=2,
                         executor_cores=2,
                         executor_memory='4GB')

# normal data processesing with Spark
df = spark.createDataFrame([('look',), ('spark',), ('tutorial',), ('spark',), ('look', ), ('python', )], ['word'])
df.show()
word_count = df.groupBy('word').count()
word_count.show()

# stop the spark cluster
raydp.stop_spark()
```

Comment: Hey, have you tried following a tutorial? This blog post is good https://medium.com/distributed-computing-with-ray/a-step-by-step-guide-to-scaling-your-first-python-application-in-the-cloud-8761fe331ef1 or can also follow https://docs.ray.io/en/releases-1.13.0/cluster/cloud.html

Comment: If there are specific errors that you need help with, edit your question and add them!